# Seeding a restful_authentication user in seeds.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, restful-authentication, seed

I'm pretty sure I understand how seeding work with respect to seeds.rb, but I can't seem to use it to stick a **restful_authentication** User object into the database.

```
User.create(:login => 'admin',
            :role => Role.find_by_name('super_admin'),
            :email => 'admin@example.com',
            :password => '123123')
```

Am I missing something?

Edit: I also tried adding the password confirmation. Still nothing.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Did you run `rake` with `--trace` option? i.e. `rake db:seed --trace`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `User.create!()` using the same parameters). This will show you any validation errors in the console.

Answer (score 1):

Password confirmation?

Comment: You may want to just check the validations and/or try to create this with the same attributes in the console and then check errors

Answer (score 1):

Have you turned the notification on? If so, the `User` model is trying to send
the email notification. If you haven't configured your email server, the create operation
will fail.

I had to do the following to work around the problem.

## 1 Modify the User model

Add a virtual attribute called `dont_notify`.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   # add a attribute
   attr_accessor dont_notify
end
```

## 2 Change the Observer code to detect the attribute.

```
class UserObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer

  def after_create(user)
    return if user.dont_notify? #notice this line 
    UserMailer.deliver_signup_notification(user)
  end

  def after_save(user)
    return if user.dont_notify? #notice this line
    UserMailer.deliver_activation(user) if user.recently_activated?
  end
end
```

## 3 Set the `dont_notify` flag during seeding

In you `seed.rb` set the flag.

```
User.create(:login => 'admin',
            :role => Role.find_by_name('super_admin'),
            :email => 'admin@example.com',
            :password => '123123',
            :password_confirmation => '123123',
            :dont_notify => true
         )
```